# satellites attitude determination TRIAD - how are orbital reference frame vectors constructed?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, orientation

I posted this same question on space.stackexchange but never received any answer. So I am posting here hoping to get an answer as this is a quite mathematical topic.

I am trying to fully understand the TRIAD algorithm for attitude determination of a satellite. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_method

So so far I know that the vectors $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$ can be constructed using measurements from different sensors. For example: if you have a sunsensor on each side of a satellite (in the x- ,y- and z-direction) and only the x-side is facing the sun you could eventually have a vector as follows $\vec{r}_1 = [100,0,0,]^T$.

But what about the vectors which are not fixed to the body of the satellite itself? How do you construct vectors for such a inertial reference frame (orbital reference frame)?

[image]

Any alternatives are welcome.

The final goal is to get the rotation matrix A.

$$A = [\vec{R}_1;\vec{R}_2; (\vec{R}_1 \times \vec{R}_2)] [\vec{r}_1; \vec{r}_2;(\vec{r}_1 \times \vec{r}_2)]^T$$

EDIT: I know ot has something to do with spherical harmonics

Answer (score 1):

Before solving for attitude you must have done orbit determination and know precisely the position of the vehicle with respect to the Earth $\vec{P}$. Then, computing the reference directions in the orbit frame is easy:

Given a reference (i.e. some star or the Sun) in the Earth frame (from some almanac), $\vec{S}_1$, you would build a reference: $\vec{R}_1=\vec{S}_1-\vec{P}$

After getting $\vec{R}_2=\vec{S}_2-\vec{P}$ by using another direction reference (i.e. some star 2),

$$
A = [\vec{R}_1;\vec{R}_2; (\vec{R}_1 \times \vec{R}_2)] [\vec{r}_1; \vec{r}_2;(\vec{r}_1 \times \vec{r}_2)]^T
$$
gives you the rotation matrix $A$ from earth frame orientation to vehicle body frame orientation.

The measurement always has error, the previous computation is not correct if the measurement has error. [See the Wikipedia article you link to to see the recommended workaround with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triad_method):
$$
A = [\vec{S};\vec{M}; (\vec{S} \times \vec{M})] [\vec{s};\vec{m}; (\vec{s} \times \vec{m})]^T
$$